# Ubuntu/MacOS cannot see RPLidar

Tags: python, macos, ubuntu, terminal, lidar

I did all steps having the 
[Manual of RPLidar](http://bucket.download.slamtec.com/351a5409ddfba077ad11ec5071e97ba5bf2c5d0a/LR002_SLAMTEC_rplidar_sdk_v1.0_en.pdf) of RPLidar, but Ubuntu and MacOS cannot connect to RPLidar and give some error like this:

> Failed to connect to the sensor due to: [Errno 2] could not open port /dev/ttyUSB0: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/dev/ttyUSB0'

no one USBs shows when search in both of terminals. (ls /dev/tty*)
Will be helpful some link or help. (Not master on Ubuntu and MacOS)

command ls /dev/

```
HAX             ptyw5
afsc_type5          ptyw6
auditpipe           ptyw7
auditsessions           ptyw8
autofs              ptyw9
autofs_control          ptywa
autofs_homedirmounter       ptywb
autofs_notrigger        ptywc
autofs_nowait           ptywd
bpf0                ptywe
bpf1                ptywf
bpf2                random
bpf3                rdisk0
console             rdisk0s1
cu.Bluetooth-Incoming-Port  rdisk0s2
disk0               rdisk0s3
disk0s1             rdisk1
disk0s2             rdisk2
disk0s3             rdisk2s1
disk1               sdt
disk2               stderr
disk2s1             stdin
dtrace              stdout
dtracehelper            systrace
fbt             tty
fd              tty.Bluetooth-Incoming-Port
fsevents            ttyp0
io8log              ttyp1
io8logmt            ttyp2
io8logtemp          ttyp3
lockstat            ttyp4
machtrace           ttyp5
nsmb0               ttyp6
null                ttyp7
oslog               ttyp8 
oslog_stream            ttyp9
pf              ttypa
pfm             ttypb
pmCPU               ttypc
profile             ttypd
ptmx                ttype
ptyp0               ttypf
ptyp1               ttyq0
```

Comment: You can simple check your dev list by `ls /dev/` and see if you have that device which you expect to reference .

Comment: @FrankAK answer is not familiar with my topic

Comment: You should show us your current system information as i said above, you should `ls /dev` it and then share your got here. and then you decide which step or where are you trouble is. Do I clear ?

Comment: @FrankAK check the topic again, i added it

Comment: As we can see there are NO device name as `ttyUSB0`, you gotta do first check why no mount this device successful ..

Comment: @FrankAK ahah, this why im asking here , how to do it ))

Comment: So, There are many reason, for example you have a BAD usb device! or you question is pure hardware problem ~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its solved. I used the Parallel on Mac and when switch the USB, instead of need to "check to Ubuntu" as debugger on Ubuntu machine